# _.map doesn't return an array of objects, but strings

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
[{name:'john',age: 24}, {name:'arian', age: 34}]
```

I want to get the following array back:

```
[{title:'john'},{title:'arian'}]
```

The following code:

```
let tableData = {
  header: [{title: 'name'}],
  data: _.map(groups, group => {
    return group.name
  })
};
```

results in: `['john', 'arian']`

but this code:

```
let tableData = {
  header: [{title: 'name'}],
  data: _.map(groups, group => {
    return {title: group.name} // <-- this line changed
  })
};
```

returns an array of length 0 for data. Why does this happen ? isn't it basically the same ?

**Update 1**

How I get groups:

```
const { groups } = this.props;
```

This is a react code.

Comment: Is groups a `const`? How are you calling this function?

Comment: yes, it's constant. I get it through react props. I will update my code.

Comment: Your code you've shown us is fine. `groups` isn't what you think it is. **Just `console.log` what groups is.**

Comment: How come the first piece of code works, and not the second one ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh The only explanation is that your input `groups` did change. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(groups))` (and post its contents) to make sure it is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stated has a very simple solution. You are doing it right, but need little change in the code

```
var obj = [{name:'john',age: 24}, {name:'arian', age: 34}];
var result = _.map(obj,(value)=>{
    return {name:value.name};
});
```

Comment: I found what was wrong, but I'm wondering what are you suggesting ?

Comment: As _.map return an array. Code issue:-  "return group.name" returns string i.e. value assigned to "name" key. But you are not returning the object as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting each member of your resultant array to be a object then you need to return that kind of object from your `map`, as simple as that. Either you use `lodash` or pure **javascript version of map**, answer is the same:

```
_.map(groups, o=>({'title': o.name}))
```

Or with native javascript Array map

```
groups.map(o=>({'title': o.name}))
```

Answer (score -4):

Why not use native `Array.prototype.map`?

```js
let data = [{name:'john',age: 24}, {name:'arian', age: 34}]

console.log(data.map( (item) => { return { title: item.name } }))
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I don't understand why people are still stuck with lodash, while the same can be achieved with a simple javascript.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, and if anything, is an unrelated comment posted as an answer

Comment: but it does solve this problem and it is a better solution. Users who navigate to this page later with the same issue will be able to solve that issue thanks to this comment. Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: Honestly, then I don't even **understand** the problem. OP should try to be more clear.

Comment: If you don't understand the question why did you post an answer and then complain that you're getting downvoted?

Comment: I haven't complained. You can't prevent people from being smartasses anyway. I have suggested a working solution for the problem OP described, using native Javascript. If this problem is releated to [tag:React], it should be tagged so. If it's not tagged it should be safe to assume solving the problem requires no React knowledge.

Comment: The OPs code works tho so it's not a working solution.

Comment: So if his code works, what is the issue why he's asking here?